# .Polyline to draw a path to the Plots from DB values?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I click an item from the drop down down list, it plots those on the map.

What I need is for it to also draw a poly line from my current location to each plot(coordinates on the map).

EDIT:

When I use:

```
  var myTrip = [{lat: -26.077740, lng: 28.010100} ,
                                      latlng];
```

it draws a poly lines from that location to all the plots but if I try to get it to draw from my current location which comes from "mylatlng" it does not work.

How do I make the mylatlng work and make it draw from my current location instead of hard coding the value from where the poly line starts?

```
  var mylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                        //fix mylatlng

                       // var myLatLng = (-26.077740, 28.010100);

                        var myTrip = [mylatlng,
                                      latlng];

                        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                            path: myTrip,
                            geodesic: true,
                            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                            strokeWeight: 2
                        });
```

The current location works for everything else that I use it for except for the polyline. Here's the declaration:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var geocoder;

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, 
            errorFunction);

        }

        function successFunction(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            codeLatLng(lat, lng)
        }

        function errorFunction() {
            alert("Geocoder failed");
        }


 function codeLatLng(lat, lng) 
  {

 //all other code here, plots, current location marker etc.

  }
```

Please note that latlng is coming from the plots which work when I hardcode myLatLng like I have said above.